# Redux Store fetch takes long, messing up a react component that uses conditional rendering | need data faster

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, redux

Edit: I'm not sure how to make this post shorter... i didn't want it to be too long, a lot of the code I posted is comments / and or can be just skimmed over quickly (first few code blocks) until you get to the rendering...

Edit2: I'm reading the react docs on this - https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html - to see if I missed something obvious. I may have...

I am struggling to create a conditional rendering of components in react (where one component depends on the values from other components) that are used to then create a D3 graph. This is my first react app, and juggling react with getting data from the redux store, with creating conditional components, with using D3 all together, has been challenging. I'm worried that I'm not doing certain things in the correct 'react' fashion, given the difficulty I'm having. The fact that my fetches are taking a long time is not helping either, since code is rendering that needs the data from those fetches, breaking my D3 graphs...

Here's what I have so far:

**All of the imports in my ByPitchKZonesApp component**

```
// Fairly certain I've got all of this imported correctly 

// Import React Components
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// Import Headers / Buttons / Select / D3 Components
import ToolButtonGroup from '../../components/AppButtons/ToolButtonGroup'; 
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
import D3ByPitchKZones from '../../components/D3ByPitchKZones';

// Import Actions (to get data)
import { fetchMlbIdsLogosColors } from '../../actions/mlb-ids-logos-colors-action';
import { fetchMlbStatcastSavantAll } from '../../actions/mlb-statcast-savant-all-action';

// Import CSS for this App
import './ByPitchKZonesApp.css'
```

**Initializing the component**

```
// My app has 2 states: 
  // pitchersOrHitters is set using the ToolButtonGroup on the page
  // selectedPlayer is  set using the Select Input
    // The values in the Select Input dropdown are conditional on the value of pitchersOrHitters

class ByPitchKZonesApp extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pitchersOrHitters: "Pitchers",
            selectedPlayer: ""
        }
    }
```

**Get data from redux store**

```
// fetchMlbStatcastSavantAll() returns a large object pitchfxData, however this is taking 10-20 seconds, which is giving me issues with the rendering
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchMlbIdsLogosColors();
    this.props.fetchMlbStatcastSavantAll();
}
```

**Button and select handlers**

```
// I believe I have this setup correctly

// Button and Select Handlers!
handlePitchHitChange = (pitchersOrHitters) => {
    this.setState({pitchersOrHitters})
}

handlePlayerChange = (selectedPlayer) => {
    this.setState({ selectedPlayer: selectedPlayer });
}
```

**Rendering**

```
render() {

    // since pitchfxData is taking so long to load, check here if the load has been completed yet
    const dataLoaded = (this.props.pitchfxData) ? "true" : false;
    const { pitchersOrHitters } = this.state;
    const { pitchfxData } = this.props;


    // Cannot render the select widget until the pitchfxData loads
    // playerSelect is the conditional component here - depends on data from the buttons
    if(dataLoaded) {

        // Values in the select widget are conditional on the button clicked, whether its Pitchers or Hitters
        if(pitchersOrHitters == "Pitchers") {
            var name_col = "pitcher_name"
        } else {
            var name_col = "batter_name"
        }

        var players = [... new Set(pitchfxData.map(pitch => pitch[name_col]))]
            .map(player => {
                return {value: player, label: player}
            });

        var playerSelect = <div className="playerSelectContainer">                      
                <Select
                    name="team-select"
                    clearable={true}
                    searchable={true}
                    onChange={this.handlePlayerChange} 
                    value={this.state.selectedPlayer} 
                    options={players} />
            </div>  
    } else {
        // load a blank div in place of the select widget if data hasnt loaded yet
        var playerSelect = <div className="playerSelectContainer"></div>
    }
```

**Props passed to button group**

```
    const pitchOrHitButtonGroup = {
        borderRadius: "25px",
        margin: "2%",
        padding: "10%",
        fontsize: "2em",
        border: "2px solid #BBB",
        gridColumns: 2, minRowHeight: "130px", 
        header: "",         
        buttons: [
            { value: "Pitchers", label: "Pitchers" },
            { value: "Hitters", label: "Hitters" },
        ]}
```

**Return the Component**

```
        return(
            <div className="pageContainer">
                <div className="hitOrPitchButtonsContainer">
                    <ToolButtonGroup
                        params={pitchOrHitButtonGroup}
                        value={this.state.pitchersOrHitters}
                        handler={this.handlePitchHitChange} />
                </div>
                {playerSelect}
                <div className="d3Container">
                    <D3ByPitchKZones
                        id={'d3-scatter'}
                        height={window.innerWidth*0.425}
                        width={window.innerWidth*0.85}
                        padding={50}
                        margin={{top:30, right:20, bottom:20, left:20}}
                        pitchfxData={pitchfxData}
                        theseGames="entireSeason"
                        pitcherOrHitter={this.state.pitcherOrHitter}
                        playerName={this.state.selectedPlayer && this.state.selectedPlayer.label} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Handle getting the redux state into props for this component**

```
function mapStateToProps(reduxState) {
    return {
        colorLogoPalette: reduxState.mlbIdsLogosColorsReducer.mlbIdsLogosColorsData,
        pitchfxData: reduxState.mlbStatcastSavantAllReducer.mlbStatcastSavantAllData
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchMlbIdsLogosColors, fetchMlbStatcastSavantAll })(ByPitchKZonesApp);*
```

With that said, my questions are:

(1) Am I conditionally rendering the select inputs correctly in the render function? I am checking what the button value is, and rendering the Select Widget {playerSelect} differently based on the value of pitchersOrHitters, which comes from the buttons. I am going to have to add additional conditional button group components that are based on this pitchersOrHitters state variable, and want to do this correctly... if not an if else in render(), then what?

(2) My app is crashing because the D3 component, which requires the pitchfxData, is rendering before the pitchfxData has been loaded (before this.props.fetchMlbStatcastSavantAll() is finished getting the pitchfxData). This is a problem, and I'm not sure how to (a) get the pitchfxData loaded faster or (b) tell the D3 component to wait until the data is loaded before rendering...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to handle conditionally rendering JSX. Usually what you have in between render and return would be put in a function and then the function is called within your JSX.

to prevent the D3 component from rendering early you can check if the props exist which you can do within return or in a separate function like my "selectPlayers" function.

there are ways my example can be condensed and rewritten but I think is a good start.

```
playerSelect = () => {
  const { pitchersOrHitters } = this.state
  const { pitchfxData } = this.props
  let name_col
  if (pitchersOrHitters == 'Pitchers') {
    name_col = 'pitcher_name'
  } else {
    name_col = 'batter_name'
  }

  const players = [...new Set(pitchfxData.map(pitch => pitch[name_col]))].map(player => {
    return { value: player, label: player }
  })

  var playerSelect = (
    <div className='playerSelectContainer'>
      <Select
        name='team-select'
        clearable
        searchable
        onChange={this.handlePlayerChange}
        value={this.state.selectedPlayer}
        options={players}
            />
    </div>
    )
    return playerSelect
}

render() {
       return(
            <div className="pageContainer">
                <div className="hitOrPitchButtonsContainer">
                    <ToolButtonGroup
                        params={pitchOrHitButtonGroup}
                        value={this.state.pitchersOrHitters}
                        handler={this.handlePitchHitChange} />
                </div>
                //check if props have loaded to conditionally render JSX
                {this.props.pitchfxData ? 
                    this.playerSelect()
                    : <div className="playerSelectContainer"></div>
                }
                //again checking if the props have loaded and if not then nothing with be rendered in place of the D3 component
                {
                this.props.pitchfxData ? 
                <div className="d3Container">
                    <D3ByPitchKZones
                        id={'d3-scatter'}
                        height={window.innerWidth*0.425}
                        width={window.innerWidth*0.85}
                        padding={50}
                        margin={{top:30, right:20, bottom:20, left:20}}
                        pitchfxData={pitchfxData}
                        theseGames="entireSeason"
                        pitcherOrHitter={this.state.pitcherOrHitter}
                        playerName={this.state.selectedPlayer && this.state.selectedPlayer.label} />
                </div>
                : 
                undefined
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```